# Big Video not reproducing video - VideoJS is not defined

Tags: video

I've uploaded an example of the big video plugin here:

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/editorials/example.html

but the video doesn't play and I get this error message in firefox:

```
ReferenceError: VideoJS is not defined
[Parar en este error] 
VideoJS.options.techOrder = ['flash'];
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you added the `video.js` script?  If you look at the source of the bigvideo website you can see a link to video.js but this file is not included in the `bigvideo.js` download.  Here is a link to the video.js website:  http://www.videojs.com/